# How to upgrade typescript so that graphql still compiles?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, graphql

After new update of typescript I started to get this error on build:

```
TS2322: Type '({ data, loading, error }: { data: any; loading: any; error: any; }) => Element' is not assignable to type '((result: QueryResult<any, OperationVariables>) => ReactNode) | (((result: QueryResult<any, OperationVariables>) => ReactNode) & string) | ... 5 more ... | (((result: QueryResult<...>) => ReactNode) & ReactPortal)'.
  Type '({ data, loading, error }: { data: any; loading: any; error: any; }) => Element' is not assignable to type '(result: QueryResult<any, OperationVariables>) => ReactNode'.
    Types of parameters '__0' and 'result' are incompatible.
      Type 'QueryResult<any, OperationVariables>' is not assignable to type '{ data: any; loading: any; error: any; }'.
        Property 'error' is optional in type 'QueryResult<any, OperationVariables>' but required in type '{ data: any; loading: any; error: any; }'.
```

Any pointer how to fix it would be great. It seems to be only with the latest typescript `3.8.2`. When I force the previous version I had `3.7.4` the error goes away.

EDIT:
The error comes from the typescript compiling so in my case when I run `react-scripts-ts build`. Also, I missed to TS error code before, so I updated the error line above.

Comment: Where is this error coming from? Within `GraphQL` or from your custom code interacting with the API ?

Comment: Type checking is stricter in 3.8. The library needs to be updated

Comment: @Zze I added EDIT with more info. Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: @AluanHaddad thanks, I'll open a github issue on the graphql project. Thanks for pointing me to the right place.

Comment: same issue with ts version `3.7.4`

Answer (score 1):

Having similar issue getting popped up during build, following helped as a workaround:

```
import { Query, QueryResult } from 'react-apollo';
    ....
{({ loading, error, data }: QueryResult<any, Record<string, any>>): JSX.Element => ...
```

Just replace `any` with whatever suits your case.

Answer (score 1):

This is a workaround so that you can continue upgrading TS.

```
<Query query={myQuery}>
    {(result) => {
        const { data, loading, error } = result;
        // ...          
    }}
</Query>
```